# what leads to the different outcome of the synchronously block function `sleep` in GUI and non GUI program

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I use synchronously block `QThread::sleep()` function to do timing, which shows number one after another by the time.

the expected running process is synchronously block current thread 2 seconds, and run the following code to change displayed number, and synchronously block another 2 seconds, and so on..., the thought works well in non GUI program.

but in GUI mode,  the label only show 9, which is the last number to be displayed.

what leads to the different outcome of the synchronous blocking function `sleep` in GUI and non GUI program?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

//slot of start timing button
void Widget::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        QThread.sleep(2);
        ui->label->setText(QString::number(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not allowing the event loop to process the events (which includes redrawing your UI). Use a `QTimer` instead of your `for` loop.

Comment: It is not a good idea to block GUI thread, you better do it asynchronously creating another signal and attaching it to QTimer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GUI needs to continually verify events such as the mouse, the keyboard, etc. and perform actions if certain conditions are met, that is called eventloop. In the case of `sleep()` it is a blocking task that does not allow the eventloop to run, generating the GUI to freeze (if you want to verify it, try to change the size of the window), so inside the GUI thread you should avoid to use that kind of functions, the blocking tasks you have to turn them into asynchronous or execute it in another thread.

But the task of the `sleep()` can be replaced by a QTimer without blocking the GUI:

***.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QTimer>
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();
    void onTimeout();
private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    int counter;
    QTimer timer;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

***.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

#include <QLabel>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    counter = 0;
    connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Widget::onTimeout);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    timer.start(2000);
}

void Widget::onTimeout()
{
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(counter));
    counter++;
    if(counter > 10){
        counter = 0;
        timer.stop();
    }
}
```

Another option is to use `QEventLoop` with `QTimer`:

```
void Widget::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        QEventLoop loop;
        QTimer::singleShot(2000, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
        loop.exec();
        ui->label->setText(QString::number(i));
    }
}
```

Update:

**what leads to the different outcome of the synchronous blocking function sleep in GUI and non GUI program?**

If you are creating a non GUI application using Qt you will also have problems, although the effect may be less visible.

In the case of the GUI as I said there is an eventloop that handles events, and among them that of repainting, I mean when you set the new text in the `QLabel`, this is not painted automatically but Qt decides the right moment. That's why when you use `QThread::sleep()` you do not have time to update the painting.

Obviously in a non GUI application, the eventloop does not verify many events as the one painted by it does not see the effect, in fact in a script that only prints numbers it does not verify any event.

To notice the problem, let's use the following example:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>

#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [](){
       qDebug()<< "hello world";
    });

    timer.start(1000);

    qDebug()<< "start blocking";
    QThread::sleep(10);
    qDebug()<< "end blocking";

    return a.exec();
}
```

We will see that nothing is printed until the `sleep()` ends, that is, blocking the eventloop that allows the `QTimer` to do its work.

Answering your comment:

- *but what still makes me puzzled is why after finishing executing sleep function, after stopping blocking current thread, the following codes can't run as normal*
- *`ui->label->setText(QString::number(i));` this statement, right after sleep function*

Asynchronous tasks such as painting have less priority than synchronous tasks, that is to say first Qt will execute the for loop and then just do the asynchronous tasks, so in the for the variable that stores the `QLabel` text is updated, that is to say 0, 1 , ..., 9, and after that, the task is handed over to the eventloop so that it just paints the last value, that is, the 9.

Note:

You can force the evenloop to update within synchronous execution with `QXXXApplication::processEvents()`, but this is often considered a bad practice, I only show it so you know it but avoid using it:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    QThread.sleep(2);
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(i));
    QApplication::processEvents();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer very much.you said that it is a blocking task that does not allow the eventloop to run, generating the GUI to freeze. `sleep` function can block current thread, but what still makes me puzzled is why after finishing executing `sleep` function, after stopping blocking current thread, the following codes can't run as normal.

Comment: `ui->label->setText(QString::number(i));` this statement, right after `sleep` function

Comment: You point out that `QApplication::processEvents` is bad practice, but you should also point it out in your `QEventLoop` example. Both are bad.